# Posting Economic model ideas?

Tags: discussion

what is the site's policy on posting original economic research or ideas that one would like to be reviewed on SE? is this the appropriate forum for posting such work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main things to avoid is (quoting from the help center):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do”

and also, generally, questions whose answer is opinion-based.

So my advice would be to try formulating the post such that it has a concrete question that avoid subjectivity. For example, asking about existing literature similar to the idea, or about ways that people have approach modelling particular phenomena.